# register form unload very well

Tags: php, codeigniter

I made a controller with code:

```
 function register()
{
$this->load->view('backend/register');
}
```

I have a form (register.php) with work well. I need to load this code in controller:

```
$names                   =   $this->input->post('name');
    $birthday                =   $this->input->post('birthday');
    $phones                  =   $this->input->post('phone');
    $emails                  =   $this->input->post('email');
    $passwords               =   $this->input->post('password');
    $rolls                   =   '0';
            $data['name']     =   $names;
            $data['email']    =   $emails;
            $data['password'] =   sha1($passwords);
            $data['phone']    =   $phones;
            $data['birthday'] =   $birthday;    
            //validate here, if the row(name, email, password) is empty or not
            if($data['name'] == '' || $data['email'] == '' || $data['password'] == '')
                continue;

            $this->db->insert('student' , $data);
            $student_id = $this->db->insert_id();

            $data2['enroll_code']   =   substr(md5(rand(0, 1000000)), 0, 7);
            $data2['student_id']    =   $student_id;
            $data2['class_id']      =   $this->input->post('class_id');
            if($this->input->post('section_id') != '') {
                $data2['section_id']    =   $this->input->post('section_id');
            }
            $data2['roll']          =   $rolls[$i];
            $data2['date_added']    =   strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
            $data2['year']          =   $this->db->get_where('settings' , array(
                                            'type' => 'running_year'
                                        ))->row()->description;

            $this->db->insert('enroll' , $data2);
    echo 'alert("Contul a fost creat cu succes!")';
    redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?login/' , 'refresh');
```

In the current form from the controller the page loads very well. When I add the code above, the page is no longer loaded. I tried to remove the code line from the controller ($ this-> load-> view ('backend / register');) + added the code that I want but with no results.
How to combine the above codes to work?

Comment: Read this https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html and also for your passwords use http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php also https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html

Comment: you are saying if user registers he/she should be redirected to `login` page after inserting the user detail to database else display the register page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are refering to using single controller function to display register page and use the same controller function to process and insert the data into database use the following:

```
function register()
{
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $names = $this->input->post('name');
        $birthday = $this->input->post('birthday');
        $phones = $this->input->post('phone');
        $emails = $this->input->post('email');
        $passwords = $this->input->post('password');
        $rolls = '0';
        $data['name'] = $names;
        $data['email'] = $emails;
        $data['password'] = sha1($passwords);
        $data['phone'] = $phones;
        $data['birthday'] = $birthday;
        //validate here, if the row(name, email, password) is empty or not
        if ($data['name'] == '' || $data['email'] == '' || $data['password'] == '')
            continue;

        $this->db->insert('student', $data);
        $student_id = $this->db->insert_id();

        $data2['enroll_code'] = substr(md5(rand(0, 1000000)), 0, 7);
        $data2['student_id'] = $student_id;
        $data2['class_id'] = $this->input->post('class_id');
        if ($this->input->post('section_id') != '') {
            $data2['section_id'] = $this->input->post('section_id');
        }
        $data2['roll'] = $rolls[$i];
        $data2['date_added'] = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
        $data2['year'] = $this->db->get_where('settings', array(
            'type' => 'running_year'
        ))->row()->description;

        $this->db->insert('enroll', $data2);
        echo 'alert("Contul a fost creat cu succes!")';
        redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?login/', 'refresh');
    } else {
        $this->load->view('backend/register');
    }

}
```

**Note: you must have `name="submit"` in your submit button since `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` is used to check if `$_POST['submit']` has value**

Simply what I've done is

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //do form processing and insert data 
}else{
    //display register page
    $this->load->view('backend/register');
}
```